# Piping ffmpeg thumbail output to another program

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, pipe, jpeg

I'm trying to capture frames from a live video stream (h.264) and pipe the resulting JPG images to a Node JS script, instead of saving these individual frames directly to .jpg files.

As a test, I created the following Node JS script, to simply capture the incoming piped data, then dump it to a file:

```
// pipe.js - test pipe output
var fs = require('fs');
var data = '';

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

var filename = process.argv[2];

process.stdin.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log('Received data chunk via pipe.');
        data += chunk;
});

process.stdin.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Data ended.');
        fs.writeFile(filename, data, err => {
                if (err) {
                        console.log('Error writing file: error #', err);
                }
        });
        console.log('Saved file.');
});

console.log('Started...  Filename = ' + filename);
```

Here's the ffmpeg command I used:

```
ffmpeg -vcodec h264_mmal -i "rtsp://[stream url]" -vframes 1 -f image2pipe - | node pipe.js test.jpg
```

This generated the following output, and also produced a 175kB file which contains garbage (unreadable as a jpg file anyway).  FYI using ffmpeg to export directly to a jpg file produced files around 25kB in size.

```
...
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264_mmal @ 0x130d3f0] Changing output format.
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:1280x720 fmt:yuvj420p to size:1280x720 fmt:yuv420p
[swscaler @ 0x1450ca0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Received data chunk via pipe.
Received data chunk via pipe.
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=7.7 Lsize=      94kB time=00:00:00.40 bitrate=1929.0kbits/s speed=1.18x
video:94kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000000%
Received data chunk via pipe.
Data ended.
Saved file.
```

You can see that the Node JS script is receiving piped data (per the "Received data via pipe" messages above.  However, it doesn't seem to be outputting a valid JPG file.  I can't find a way to specifically request that ffmpeg output JPG format, since there is no -vcodec option for JPG.  I tried using -vcodec png and outputting to a .png file, but the resulting file was about 2MB in size and also unreadable as a png file.

Is this a problem caused by using utf8 encoding, or am I doing something else wrong?

Thanks for any advice.

UPDATE:  OK I got it to send a single jpg image correctly.  The issue was in the way Node JS was capturing the stream data.  Here's a working script:

```
// pipe.js - capture piped binary input and write to file
var fs = require('fs');
var filename = process.argv[2];

console.log("Opening " + filename + " for binary writing...");

var wstream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);

process.stdin.on('readable', () => {
        var chunk = '';
        while ((chunk = process.stdin.read()) !== null) {
                wstream.write(chunk);   // Write the binary data to file
                console.log("Writing chunk to file...");
        }
});

process.stdin.on('end', () => {
        // Close the file
        wstream.end();
});
```

However, now the problem is this: when piping the output of ffmpeg to this script, how can I tell when one JPG file ends and another one begins?

ffmpeg command:

```
 ffmpeg -vcodec h264_mmal -i "[my rtsp stream]" -r 1 -q:v 2 -f singlejpeg - | node pipe.js test_output.jpg
```

The test_output.jpg file continues to grow as long as the script runs.  How can I instead know when the data for one jpg is complete and another one has started?
According to [this](http://www.file-recovery.com/jpg-signature-format.htm), jpeg files always start with FF D8 FF and end with FF D9, so I guess I can check for this ending signature and start a new file at that point... any other suggestions?

Comment: Can the saved jpg be piped to node successfully?

Comment: No, when piping the JPEG file directly, I get an output file that's almost 2x size of original.  However, when piping a text file, I get the exact text file out.  This is obviously an issue with the character encoding, but I can't figure out how to simply use BYTES.  I tried the 'binary' encoding and got a smaller file, but still not exact.

Comment: OK I figured out the issue, but still not completely successful - see the question...

Comment: Keep in mind, `FF D8 FF` is a signature but may occur anywhere in the bit stream. There might be more JFIF spec to read to find the full header specification.

Comment: I know this is old, but did you manage to detect when the file ends?

Comment: @sebastian-greco I think the answer is to check for the ending FF D9 characters.

Comment: @RyanGriggs yes, thank you. I ended up doing exactly that (but with IEND chuck for PNG in my case), thanks for the answer. Works like a charm!